# Ui Applicatiopn class use in other class

Tags: blackberry

(public class GPSDemo extends UiApplication) its a class name 
i want to use this class in this code. i am make a object of this class but throw the exception

here is the place where we use it 
popRunnable = new Runnable() 
                   {
                         public void run() 
                        {
                              /*StartUpScreen mainScreen = new StartUpScreen();
                                pushScreen(mainScreen); */

```
                             GPSDemo mainScreen =new GPSDemo();

                            // mainScreen.enterEventDispatcher();
                             //pushScreen(mainScreen);  
                    }
             };
```

who we use it

Answer (score 0):

UiApplication and MainScreen are different things

```
public class Main extends UiApplication{
Main() {
    pushScreen(new GPSDemo());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Main app = new Main();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}

class GPSDemo extends MainScreen {
   GPSDemo() {
    this.setTitle("GPSDemo");
}
```

}